# How to get Assets.xcassets file names in an Array (or some data structure?)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use Swift to iterate over the images I have put into my Assets folder. I'd like to iterate over them and insert them into a `.nib` file later, but so far I cannot find how to get something like:

`let assetArray = ["image1.gif", "image2.gif", ...]`

Is this possible? I've been playing with `NSBundle.mainBundle()` but couldn't find anything on this. Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Are you suggesting I load 30+ images by typing that out 30 times? I'm fairly new to iOS development, but that seems so bizarre to me.

Comment: I'm with https://stackoverflow.com/users/85192/patrick-c - there are several similar questions on here which all have the same answer - "Don't use Asset Catalogues", but seriously, that's not an answer!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assets.xcassets is not a folder but an archive containing all the images using Assets.car as its filename.

If you really want to read the assets file then you need to use some library that can extract the contents of the file like this [one](https://github.com/Marxon13/iOS-Asset-Extractor).

Or you can create a bundle in your project and drag all the images you have there.  In my case, I have Images.bundle in my project. To get the filenames you can do the following:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL
let assetURL = bundleURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Images.bundle")
let contents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(assetURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey], options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)

for item in contents
{
  print(item.lastPathComponent)
}
```

SWIFT 3/4 Version:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
let assetURL = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("Images.bundle")

do {
  let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: assetURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.nameKey, URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey], options: .skipsHiddenFiles)

  for item in contents
  {
      print(item.lastPathComponent)
  }
}
catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Seems to be out of date for Swift 3 or higher.  How is it done today?

Comment: I added the Swift 3 version just now.

Comment: Very cool.  But it crashes for me on the `try!`, when I do a `do catch` it results in catching this error: `The file “Images.bundle” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.`

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “Assets.car” couldn’t be opened."

Comment: Added a handler for the try statement, in case file is not found.

Comment: Thx for you answer!