# Get a list of Image names from Asset Catalog

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a bunch of images in my Asset Catalog: img01, img02, img03 ...

Is it possible to get an Array of image names for all images starting with `img` or the count of those images. If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Did you try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317444/how-to-get-assets-xcassets-file-names-in-an-array-or-some-data-structure

Comment: Your links does not solve my issue.

Answer (score -3):

I had this problem too.
I just created an array manually in the ViewController with all the images in id.
But it was a lot of typing work.