# How to create an array of images from assets folder in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, assets

I'm a newbie on Swift development and in these months I'm going to personalize some basics projects like the dice app.

At the moment I have one problem that is not easy to find on StackOverflow:

1) how to create an array of the dice faces from a folder located in assets.xcassets 
(currently I have manually loaded the 6 faces of the dice into an array called diceArray but if the dice has 50 faces it would be a waste of time)

My actual code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!


    @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let diceArray = [ #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceTwo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceThree"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFour"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFive"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceSix")]

        diceImageView1.image = diceArray.randomElement()
        diceImageView2.image = diceArray.randomElement()

    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38319754/8374890

Comment: Why would dice have 50 faces?

Comment: @Rob https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRs9eD40wE5SDzbreOtNwNDmDMKeeII8wiy4OfuXP5z35I1PWno&s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think load 50 images on an array is not a good idea. I know you are following a tutorial.
For more same types of images, you can try this.

- Try all image name prefixes are the same. Like: Dice1, Dice2,
  Dice3... Dice50 // Here the prefix is **Dice**
- Get a random number between **0-49**
- Suppose you get a random number 30. Now you can simply get the image by this way

  ```
  let randomNumber = 30  
  let image = UIImage(named: "Dice\(randomNumber)")
  ```

In this way not need to create an array with 50 images.

Comment: in this case, how can I take the images that are stored in assets.xcassets?

Comment: By this you can get the image from assets.xcassets:  UIImage.init(named: "Dice\(randomNumber)")

Comment: thank you @Faysal Ahmed! I solved the first problem with this code: let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...50)
let image = UIImage.init(named: "Dice\(randomNumber)")

Answer (score 4):

One simple method is to name all images with fixed prefix and number. Name the images as `face1`,`face2`...`face50`

```
var imagesArr = (0...50).compactMap { UIImage(named: "face\($0)") }
```

or

```
var imagesArr = [UIImage]()
(0...50).forEach { imagesArr.append(UIImage(named: "face\($0)")!) }
```

Answer (score 1):

What would your array contain ? UIImage ? If so, just read them from assets with

```
var myImagesArray: [UIImage]
// Do this for each image.
let image = UIImage(named: "aName") ?? UIImage()
myImagesArray.append(image)
```

you could store a name for the image in array:

```
var myImagesArray: [(faceNum: Int, name: String, image: UIImage)]
let image = UIImage(named: "face1") ?? UIImage()
let faceNum = 1
myImagesArray.append((1, "face1",image))
```

When you load images, you may test that

```
myImagesArray[i].num
```

is not already used